# "[aapt] ERROR: Unknown option '--generate-dependencies'" for ant debug of HelloWorld

Tags: android

Trying to create/run the HelloWorld android app, building via `ant debug` fails with an unknown option in aapt. Nothing has been done to the project aside from generation itself with `android create project`

What causes this error? How are projects created with android create built?

---

```
$ ant debug
...
[renderscript] No renderscript files to compile.
       [echo] ----------
       [echo] Handling Resources...
       [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
       [aapt] ERROR: Unknown option '--generate-dependencies'
       [aapt] Android Asset Packaging Tool
       ...aapt usage...
```

[full output (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/1v4Y0wxh)

The project was created with

```
$ android create project -t 2 -p ./HelloWorld -a HelloWorldActivity -k com.example.helloworld
```

ant is v1.8.2 
android-sdk version is r15-1

```
$ android list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
 id: 1 or "android-8"
 Name: Android 2.2
 Type: Platform
 API level: 8
 Revision: 2
 Skins: WQVGA432, WQVGA400, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, HVGA, WVGA854
 ABIs : armeabi
----------
 id: 2 or "android-13"
 Name: Android 3.2
 Type: Platform
 API level: 13
 Revision: 1
 Skins: WXGA (default)
 ABIs : armeabi
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem too after upgrading the android-sdk package in my distro.

Run the sdk manager ('android sdk' from the command line) and upgrade all of the packages, specifically the SDK Platform Tools package.